# How to select between e-ticket, mobile ticket and selfprint ticket to click on it

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

here is my element:

```
<div id="ctl00_MasterContent_FareOptionsWebPart_FareOptionsFares_ctl123_FarePoint_Outbound28_1" class="FareOptionsFarePoint Outbound Single F28 J1 fakecheck filtered fakechecked" **data-fulfilment="ToD Kiosk SelfPrint MobileTicket eTicket"** radid="28_1" fare="28" data-selectable="1">£35.00</div>
```

I can't use any other tags because all are dynamic. Only I can use to locate is data-fulfilment.

1 - If e-ticket available then it should be a click. 
2 - If Mobile Ticket available then it should be a click.

Below is my locator:

//eticket

```
private By _cel = By.xpath("//*[@data-fulfilment='ToD Kiosk SelfPrint MobileTicket eTicket']");
```

//mobile ticket if e-ticket not available

```
private By _celM = By.xpath("//*[@data-fulfilment='ToD Kiosk SelfPrint MobileTicket']");
```

my code is below:

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(_table3);

List <WebElement> row = element.findElements(_row);

System.out.println("Up to now I find  " + getTextFromElement(_row) + " element on page.");

System.out.println("No of Rows: " + row.size());

List <WebElement> cel = element.findElements(_cel);

System.out.println("Up to now I find  " + getTextFromElement(_cel) + " element on page.");

System.out.println("No of Cell: " + cel.size());

String SelfPrint = " SelfPrint ";



if (cel.contains(SelfPrint)) {

                clickOnElement(_cel);               
            }  
else
 {

                clickOnElement(_celM);

            }
```

My question is How I can select between e-ticket, mobile ticket and self-print ticket available or not? please guide me with coding as well.

Thank you

Comment: <div id="ctl00_MasterContent_FareOptionsWebPart_FareOptionsFares_ctl160_FarePoint_Inbound308_8" class="FareOptionsFarePoint Inbound Single F308 J8 fakecheck filtered fakechecked" data-fulfilment="ToD Kiosk SelfPrint MobileTicket eTicket" radid="308_8" fare="308" data-selectable="1">£18.50</div>



This is my element. sorry, it does not display after 'here is my element:'

Answer (score 0):

If only one or the other option will be available (your _cel element or your _celm element), you could just create a single By selector that would work for both, and click on it.

Based on your example XPaths, this would work in both scenarios (provided there are no other elements that contain "ToD Kiosk SelfPrint MobileTicket "data-fulfillment attribute).

```
private by _cel = By.XPath("//*[starts-with(@Data-Fulfilment, 'ToD Kiosk SelfPrint MobileTicket')]");
```

See [Xpath Cheatsheet](https://devhints.io/xpath)

Since both elements have the Data-Fulfilment attribute start with "ToD Kiosk SelfPrint MobileTicket", this would work for both. So long as only one is on the page at the time. Simply clicking with this selector should work.